# PyMC3 - How to set the matrix shape of the beta distribution

Tags: python, theano, montecarlo, pymc3, pymc

I tried to recreate the [Multilabel logistic regression](https://docs.pymc.io/notebooks/variational_api_quickstart.html) example from the PyMC3 API guide with the attached [data set (Production.csv)](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1UCWs883F9WCO_CtCrP64je7r3aPKoaAT).

In the step of creating `pm.Model()` I run into difficultiies.The matrix dimensions do not work out. I do not understand why a (4,3) matrix is used in the API example and so I have difficulties to convert the example to my problem.

Thank you for your time and understanding!

Cheers
Linus

I attached my full code, because I do not use all columns of the data set.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from math import *
import theano
import theano.tensor as tt
import pandas as pd
import pymc3 as pm
from sklearn import preprocessing 

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

data = pd.read_csv("Production.csv") 
data_hmc = data.copy()

X_hmc = data_hmc.iloc[:, [False, True, True, True, False, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True,]]
y_hmc = data_hmc.iloc[:, [False, False, False, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]]

le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
y_hmc = y_hmc.apply(le.fit_transform) 

X_train_hmc, X_test_hmc, y_train_hmc, y_test_hmc = train_test_split(X_hmc, y_hmc, test_size = 0.20) 

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler  
scaler = StandardScaler()  
scaler.fit(X_train_hmc)

X_train_hmc = scaler.transform(X_train_hmc)  
X_test_hmc = scaler.transform(X_test_hmc) 


Xt = theano.shared(X_train_hmc)
yt = theano.shared(y_train_hmc)


with pm.Model() as hmc:

    # Coefficients for features
    β = pm.Normal('β', 0, sd=1e2, shape=(61482, 3))
    # Transoform to unit interval
    a = pm.Flat('a', shape=(3,))
    p = tt.nnet.softmax(Xt.dot(β) + a)

    observed = pm.Categorical('obs', p=p, observed=yt)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the `iris` dataset, `(4,3)` is (number of predictors, number of labels).  Note that those predictors are continuous.  Going from how you load your data, it appears that you are trying to predict `FanOn` and have (naively) 14 predictors, thus the shape for `β` would be `(14,2)`.  However, most of your predictors aren't continuous, and some look categorical (e.g., `CupState`). The binary ones are fine, but categoricals need to be expanded as dummies vars. Basically, once you get an `X` matrix with all binary or continuous entries, the number of columns will be the number of rows of `β`.

Also, a couple predictors never change, so drop those.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, I did not have time to go through it before. They only question left is, why is it a `(14,2)` matrix? Where does this second dimension come from? Is it `FanOn` with 0 and 1?

Comment: Or is it the X_hmc and y_hmc vector?

Comment: @Linus Yes, it is from the predicted category, `FanOn`, where 2 is the number of levels (labels) it has.